# how to get this program to skip switch functios so it doesnt output zero(s) infront of smaller input

Tags: c, switch-statement

I can't figure out how to skip the unnecessary switches.

if tried replacing continues with breaks and if else statements that would unfortunately just stop it at the first number instead of skipping switches.

```
            if ( number > 0 && number < 10000 ) {
                switch ( thou_place ) {
                case ( 0 ):
                    printf("zero ");

                    break;
                    case ( 1 ):
                    printf("one ");

                    break;
                    case ( 2 ):
                    printf ("two ");

                    break;
                    case ( 3 ):
                    printf ("three ");

                    break;
                    case ( 4 ):
                    printf ("four ");

                    break;
                    case ( 5 ):
                    printf ("five ");

                    break;
                    case ( 6 ):
                    printf("six ");

                    break;
                    case ( 7 ):
                    printf ("seven ");

                    break;
                    case ( 8 ):
                    printf ("eight ");

                    break;
                    case ( 9 ):
                    printf ("nine ");

                    break;
                }   


                switch ( hun_place ) {
                case ( 0 ):
                    printf("zero ");

                    break;
                    case ( 1 ):
                    printf("one ");

                    break;
                    case ( 2 ):
                    printf ("two ");

                    break;
                    case ( 3 ):
                    printf ("three ");

                    break;
                    case ( 4 ):
                    printf ("four ");

                    break;
                    case ( 5 ):
                    printf ("five ");

                    break;
                    case ( 6 ):
                    printf("six ");

                    break;
                    case ( 7 ):
                    printf ("seven ");

                    break;
                    case ( 8 ):
                    printf ("eight ");

                    break;
                    case ( 9 ):
                    printf ("nine ");

                    break;
                }       


                switch ( ten_place ) {
                case ( 0 ):
                    printf("zero ");

                    break;
                    case ( 1 ):
                    printf("one ");

                    break;
                    case ( 2 ):
                    printf ("two ");

                    break;
                    case ( 3 ):
                    printf ("three ");

                    break;
                    case ( 4 ):
                    printf ("four ");

                    break;
                    case ( 5 ):
                    printf ("five ");

                    break;
                    case ( 6 ):
                    printf("six ");

                    break;
                    case ( 7 ):
                    printf ("seven ");

                    break;
                    case ( 8 ):
                    printf ("eight ");

                    break;
                    case ( 9 ):
                    printf ("nine ");

                    break;
                }
```

I can't figure out how to skip the unnecessary switches.output would say "zero one two three" instead of the desired "one two three" for an input of 123, "zero zero one two" instead of a desired output of "one two"  for an input of 12 so on and so on.

Comment: Can you tell please that how did you initialised `thou_place`, `hun_place` and `ten_place`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your logic. For example, you need to print "zero" in thousand's place only if the number itself is greater than 1000.

Simple fix for this in `case 0`:

```
switch(thou_place) {
    case ( 0 ):
        if(number > 1000)
            printf("zero ");

        break;

    ...
}
```

Similar modifications are needed in hundred's and ten's places.

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, what you need is the program to output a word `for` each digit of the decimal representation of the number. Notice the replication you have in your code? You should [not repeat yourself](https://www.artima.com/intv/dry.html) and the C language (along with most others) provides a construct to do just that: loops.

Instead of the `if ( number > 0 && number < 10000 )`, you could loop (which is also doing a check) and, for each step (*i.e.* in the body of the loop), use your `switch`.

The pseudo-code goes:

```
for digit in get_decimal_digits(number):
    switch (digit):
        case 0: print 'zero'
        case 1: print 'one'
        // ...
```

To improve clarity, you could even make your `switch` a function. Furthermore, to learn about these (it's a bit more advanced), you could consider using a `char **digit_words` allowing you to replace the whole `switch` with a `printf("%s", digit_words[digit])` (but be careful about range checking!).

This solves your issue; the actual C implementation is left as an exercise.

Comment: Why are all answers to this question being downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

[@PiCTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7844823/picto) [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56205357/3975177) the DRY-principle.

I'd suggest a different solution for the overall problem:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>  // EXIT_FAILURE
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), puts()

void tell(int value)
{
    static char const * const digit[] = {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five",
        "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"
    };

    if (value < 0) {  // handle the sign and make value positive
        printf("minus ");
        value *= -1;
    }

    if (value / 10)
        tell(value / 10);

    printf("%s ", digit[value % 10]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int value;
    if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) {
        fputs("Input error. :(\n\n", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    tell(value);
    puts("\n");
}
```

#### Procedure:

Input: `-1234567890`

```
tell(-1234567890)  --> "minus "
tell(123456789)
tell(12345678)
tell(1234567)
tell(123456)
tell(12345)
tell(1234)
tell(123)
tell(12)
tell(1) ... recursion ends because 1 / 10 == 0
printf("%s ", digit[1 % 10])  --> "one "
printf("%s ", digit[12 % 10])  --> "two "
printf("%s ", digit[123 % 10])  --> "three "
printf("%s ", digit[1234 % 10])  --> "four "
printf("%s ", digit[12345 % 10])  --> "five "
printf("%s ", digit[123456 % 10])  --> "six "
printf("%s ", digit[1234567 % 10])  --> "seven "
printf("%s ", digit[12345678 % 10])  --> "eight "
printf("%s ", digit[123456789 % 10])  --> "nine "
printf("%s ", digit[1234567890 % 10])  --> "zero "
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (number > 0 && number < 10000)
    {
        switch (thou_place)
        {
        case (1) :
            printf("one ");
            break;
        case (2) :
            printf("two ");
            break;
        case (3) :
            printf("three ");
            break;
        case (4) :
            printf("four ");
            break;
        case (5) :
            printf("five ");
            break;
        case (6) :
            printf("six ");
            break;
        case (7) :
            printf("seven ");
            break;
        case (8) :
            printf("eight ");
            break;
        case (9) :
            printf("nine ");
            break;
        }
        switch (hun_place)
        {
        case (0) :
            if (thou_place != 0)
                printf("zero ");
                break;
        case (1) :
            printf("one ");
            break;
        case (2) :
            printf("two ");
            break;
        case (3) :
            printf("three ");
            break;
        case (4) :
            printf("four ");
            break;
        case (5) :
            printf("five ");
            break; 
        case (6) :
            printf("six ");
            break;
        case (7) :
            printf("seven ");
            break; 
        case (8) :
                printf("eight ");
                break; 
        case (9) :
                printf("nine ");
                break;
       }
       switch (ten_place)
       {
           case (0) :
           {

                 if ((thou_place == 0) && (hun_place == 0))  {

                 }
                 else if (thou_place == 0 && hun_place != 0){
                     printf("zero ");
                     break;
                 }
                 else {
                     printf("zero ");
                     break;
                 }
            }

            case (1) :
               printf("one ");
               break;
           case (2) :
               printf("two ");
               break;
           case (3) :
              printf("three ");
              break;
           case (4) :
              printf("four ");
              break;
          case (5) :
              printf("five ");
              break;
          case (6) :
              printf("six ");
              break;
         case (7) :
             printf("seven ");
             break;
         case (8) :
             printf("eight ");
             break;
         case (9) :
             printf("nine ");
             break;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain what you've changed in the code and why does it solve the problem?